# Relocation of option and answer key

Tags: php

I want to prepare questions for my students. There are questions in the school's database. The table is as follows:

```
| id | qcontent                                                                     | o1  | o2   | o3  |
|----|------------------------------------------------------------------------------|-----|------|-----|
| 1  | Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.   | ab  | ba   | ce  |
| 2  | Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s | ce  | sas  | de  |
| 3  | Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text.           | ase | sded | def |
```

The correct answers are the `o1` option.

```
<?php


foreach($employee as $element) {

    echo $element->id . ". question: " .$element->qcontent . "<br>";  
    echo "A) " .$element->o1. "<br>";  
    echo "B) " .$element->o2. "<br>";  
    echo "C) " .$element->o3. "<br>";   
    echo "D) " .$element->o4. "<br>";   
    echo "E) " .$element->o5. "<br>";  

}

echo "<hr>";
echo "Answers:";

foreach($employee as $element) {

    echo $element->id. " - " .$element->o1. "<br>"; 

}
```

When I print the questions, all the right answers are option-A.
How can we generate the location of the questions and the answer key?

Comment: Put the answers into an array, [`shuffle()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.shuffle.php) it, and then loop through the array and output each item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would put the answers into an array and shuffle it. Then I would store the correct answer in an answer_key for output at the end.

```
<?php


foreach($employee as $element) {
    echo $element->id . ". question: " .$element->qcontent . "<br>"; 

    // put answers in an array
    $answers[0] = $element->01; 
    $answers[1] = $element->02;
    $answers[2] = $element->03;
    $answers[3] = $element->04;
    $answers[4] = $element->05;

    // randomize answers
    shuffle($answers);
    echo "A) " .$answers[0]. "<br>";  
    echo "B) " .$answers[1]. "<br>";  
    echo "C) " .$answers[2]. "<br>";   
    echo "D) " .$answers[3]. "<br>";   
    echo "E) " .$answers[4]. "<br>";  

   // add answer to answer key
   $answer_key[$element->id] = array_slice(array('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'), array_search($element->01, $answers), 1);
}


echo "<hr>";
echo "Answers:";

foreach($employee as $element) {

    // Output the correct answers
    echo $element->id. " - " .implode(answer_key[$element->id]). "<br>"; 

}
```

Comment: Be aware, that if employees share the same $element->id it will overwrite. But I'm not sure how your tables are setup (e.g. if they join on an employee table, or if there's another row for employees in your question/answer table).

Comment: Thank you. The first question appears at the bottom of the page, and what could be the reason for it differently? It also says "Array" in the answer key [screenshot](https://imgur.com/kEHdB5Z) - Is it possible to put the alphabet of the question in the answer key instead of the option content? For example 1- B, 2-D

Comment: That should fix the array problem. Also -- the answers will now only display the correct letter (and not the answer).

Comment: I'm not sure why the first question would appear at the end of the list of questions. I can't see the bottom of the questions in your screenshot. Is the first question missing entirely? Or does it appear at then end?

Comment: Sorry to answer you late. I get the error `Warning: implode (): Invalid arguments passed in` in the options.

Comment: Working. Thank you Jeff Vdovjak from Turkey!

Answer (score 0):

By using `shuffle()` and making an array of all possible column of name:

```
<?php
// make array of all possible keys
$keys = ['o1', 'o2', 'o3', 'o4', 'o5'];
foreach($employee as $element) {
    // convert object to array
    $element = (array)$element;

    // shuffle it
    shuffle($keys);

    echo $element['id'] . ". question: " .$element['qcontent'] . "<br>";

    echo "A) " .$element[$keys[0]] . "<br>";  
    echo "B) " .$element[$keys[1]] . "<br>";  
    echo "C) " .$element[$keys[2]] . "<br>";   
    echo "D) " .$element[$keys[3]] . "<br>";   
    echo "E) " .$element[$keys[4]] . "<br>";  

}

echo "<hr>";
echo "Answers:";

foreach($employee as $element) {
    echo $element->id. " - " .$element->o1. "<br>";
}
```

Comment: how to generate the answer key? I think you read my question missing.